# SVG line animation using Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I am literally a crawling baby in snap SVG and given that the amount of resources available online is not sufficient for a Rookie like me, I thought I would ask here. I want to learn how to do this animation that I have generated in SVG using CSS3 animations however I recently found out that, FF, IE have some issues with CSS3 animations and CSS3 transforms in SVG, so I worked only with webkit and i decided to use Snap SVG for the others, I think you know what I mean. Any how, this is a glimpse of the animation:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="711.1px" height="717.1px" viewBox="0 0 711.1 717.1" enable-background="new 0 0 711.1 717.1" xml:space="preserve">


<circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke="#FD4F00" stroke-width="66" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="355.55" cy="358.55" r="285.956"/>

</svg>
```

This is the CSS3 animation:

```
.circle {
stroke-dasharray: 2000;
stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
-webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle, to see the Full animation in action](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/djfmzkhg/) so you can see what I am talking about here.

Thanks for your help, I apologize as I am really new in Snap SVG and I really dont know how to achieve that animation so I am hoping to learn from this mini project.

EDIT: Alright so I have completed the animation [Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairanwar2/oc2aus6w/2/). Now the only problem is this,that how to adjust the repeatCount using snap.svg ? Could you please tell me how to adjust the repeatCount in Snap.svg ? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/djfmzkhg/3/)**

**Update**

I really like your improvements, pure css.
Now since I'm not sure what you need help with I remade my answer but with your new fiddle.

so the animation run a set amount of times:

```
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate 3 forwards;
```

**Note**
Consider adding all the prefixes so you have both `-wekkit-animation` and `animation` and so you have support for none webkit browsers.

**Cross Browser**
Animation:

```
-webkit-animation: 
-moz-animation:  
-o-animation:
```

Keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME {
    //code
}
@-moz-keyframes NAME {
    //code
}
@-o-keyframes NAME {
    //code
}
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    //code
}
```

```css
.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate 3 forwards;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) ;
}
.circle1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate 3 forwards;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) ;
}
.circle2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate 3 forwards;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) ;
}
.circle3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate 3 forwards;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 711.1 717.1" enable-background="new 0 0 711.1 717.1" xml:space="preserve">
  
  
<circle class="circle" fill="none" stroke="#FD4F00" stroke-width="66" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="355.55" cy="358.55" r="285.956"/>
<circle class="circle1" fill="none" stroke="#FD4F00" stroke-width="3.0819" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="355.55" cy="358.55" r="233.497"/>
<circle class="circle2" fill="none" stroke="#FD4F00" stroke-width="2.8006" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="355.55" cy="358.55" r="212.186"/>
<circle class="circle3" fill="none" stroke="#FD4F00" stroke-width="2.5572" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="355.55" cy="358.55" r="193.744"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, Yeah !! its kinda  cool however, I wanted to take it one step ahead by being able to animate back into the same position, if you know what I mean, thats where the real problem starts.

Comment: You want it to animate forwards and backwards a set amout of times?

Comment: exactly, forwards and backwards a set amount of times.

Comment: Well thats using CSS3 however have you tried it using Snap.svg , because theres where the real challenge lies, i tried the same thing at first but i realized that its not cross-browser compatible. I tried to get the same effect using Snap but I could not nail it. I hope you can.

Comment: You need to add the prefixes to animation and keyframes this will give it cross browser support. If you want support for IE 9 and IE 10 then there is a spesial prefix just search "IE animation prefix".

Comment: yes ! @DJDavid98 Miss Lea's Recipe to this issue is quite amazing. will chk it out. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm pretty late here, but I Wanted to answer the last question in your edit.

http://jsfiddle.net/oc2aus6w/9/

The general idea is to call the original function as the callback for the end of the animation.

code below for those who cannot see the fiddle:

```
var s = Snap.select('#circle')
s1 = s.select('circle:nth-child(1)');
s2 = s.select('circle:nth-child(2)');
s3 = s.select('circle:nth-child(3)');
s4 = s.select('circle:nth-child(4)');

s1.attr({
      transform: 'r-90'
    });
s2.attr({
  transform: 'r-90'
});
s3.attr({
  transform: 'r-90'
});
s4.attr({
  transform: 'r-90'
});
function circleAnim() {  
    Snap.animate(2000,4000,function(value){
        s1.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray':value
        });
                s2.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray':value
        });
        s3.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray':value
        });
        s4.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray':value
        });
    },3000, null, function(){
        Snap.animate(4000,2000,function(value){
            s1.attr({
                'stroke-dasharray':value
            });
            s2.attr({
                'stroke-dasharray':value
            });
            s3.attr({
                'stroke-dasharray':value
            });
            s4.attr({
                'stroke-dasharray':value
            });
        }, 3000, null, circleAnim);    
    });
}

circleAnim();
```